# Method for full-screen vertically-centered HTML page?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a valid cross-browser solution for an HTML page which:

1. Consumes 100% of the screen height, with no overflow (i.e. no scrolling)
2. has a vertically (and horizontally) centered `<div>` which will hold the main content

I know vertical centering is possible when the wrapping container has a static height. Is adjusting this height to browser window height something feasable? (Preferably, no JS should be used.)

Comment: Difficult with no JS as HTML/CSS has no way of knowing what the height of the browser window is. I think this is only going to be possible with JS detecting the height of the browser window (and of course changes to this height if a user resizes) and setting the static elements height that way.

Comment: vertcenter or deadcenter from http://reisio.com/examples/ should cover the tricky bits

Comment: @reisio - wonderful examples! Can you please post this as an answer so I can upvote properly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Depends on what you mean with "cross browser". Following works fine with all current, standards compatible ones (thus not IE6):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body, #a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#a {
    display: table;
}

#b {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#content {
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**Live example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mGPmr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is simply not possible without JavaScript, at least not with CSS2 or earlier (not sure if CSS3 makes this possible, someone clarify on that).

The other provided answers require absolute width and height for the element; I assumed no such requirement. There's no way to center a flowing element vertically which is what you usually want, given that you don't know the aspect ratio of the browser window to reliably use fixed-size containers for content.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.  It looks to work in IE6 as well:

```
<html> <head>

<script type="text/javascript"> </script>

<style type="text/css">

#container {    height: 100%;   width: 100%;    position: relative; }


#content {
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%; }


</style>


</head> <body>

<div id="container">
        <div id="content"></div> </div>

</body> </html>
```