# How to make my div vertically in the middle?

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Method for full-screen vertically-centered HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802433/method-for-full-screen-vertically-centered-html-page)

Pls tell me how to make my div appear vertically in the middle of the page.

Comment: u picked your answer and best one yourself. couldn't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this one.

In your html:

```
<div id="tbl">
 <div id="tbl_cell">
   <div id="content"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

In your css:

```
html, body, #tbl {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

#tbl {
 display: table;
}

#tbl_cell {
 display: table-cell;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#content {
 border: 1px solid red;
 background-color: #000;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: auto;
}
```