# How to vertically align a div in the body?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I would like to vertically align a div (`rectangle`), this div doesn't have any parents, i created one (`container`) to use the `vertical-align` property but i could remove it if someone knows a better way.

I just want to center a rectangle into the `body` div (horizontally and vertically) and make it responsive.

Here is what i tried but it doesn't work (the rectangle stay close to the top of the window):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .rectangle {
                width: 88%;
                height: 87%;
                margin: auto;
                padding:10px;
                background:red;
                display:inline-block;
                vertical-align:middle;
            }

            .container {
                text-align: center;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="rectangle">
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to achieve only using CSS or do we need javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to center a <div> on a page vertically and horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356809/best-way-to-center-a-div-on-a-page-vertically-and-horizontally)

Comment: If you know width and height why not to calculate margins yourself: `margin: 6.5% 6%`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802433/method-for-full-screen-vertically-centered-html-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .rectangle {

            background: #000;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            }

            .container {
                width: 100%; /* Firefox needs this */

            height: 100%; /* Height can be anything */

            /* WebKit (Chrome & Safari) */
            display: -webkit-box;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;

            /* Firefox */
            display: -moz-box;
            -moz-box-pack: center;
            -moz-box-align: center;

            /* IE */
            display: -ms-box;
            -ms-box-pack: center;
            -ms-box-align: center;

            /* Native CSS */
            display: box;
            box-pack: center;
            box-align: center;

            background: red;

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="rectangle">
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Internet Explorer 10 supports an alternative, the -ms-flex-align property.
Firefox supports an alternative, the -moz-box-align property.
Safari, Opera, and Chrome support an alternative, the -webkit-box-align property.
Note: Flexible boxes are not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to go about this with CSS-only.  Since you've tagged this as CSS3, we can use some newer approaches to achieve this.  Also, Chris Coyer has done some great write-ups about vertical centering with CSS.  Some links are:

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/

If you know the height of the element you want to center, you can position it absolutely and account for it's width/height with negative margins.

Another way is to set up the element and body to use css display tables.

Another emerging option is the flexbox spec, which handles a lot of the heavy lifting for you.  Some more information on flexbox can be found here:

http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And an example of how one might mix flexbox with other styling:

http://css-tricks.com/replicating-google-hangouts-chat/

I personally like the translate option the best, but as flexbox support grows, this type of layout will be most likely easiest that way.